# How do you view class files in Eclipse package explorer?

Tags: java, eclipse

The compiled classes directory is hidden by default, can I show it in the Package Explorer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but in the Navigator view.

Comment: Window->Short View->Navigator. That should give you the hierarchy of all files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

add it as an external class folder in project properties -> java build path -> libraries

Comment: I added it, but it doesn't show in the project explorer. Oh well, not a big deal.